# Hide promoted links in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013

I created a webpage containing various promoted link tiles. This page is my default page (when the user logons he/she is redirectedto this page). Based upon the group to which the user belongs I want to show some specific promoted link tiles and hide the rest of the promoted link tiles.

For example, my webpage contains 4 Promoted Link tiles.

For a normal user I want to show only 2 Promoted Link tiles and hide the rest of the tiles.
Whereas for admin I want to show all the Promoted Link tiles.

Or I thought of having different pages for different groups, but I couldn't find any setting in SharePoint 2013 to have different default pages for different groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the above thing is not possible in SharePoint.
For every user there will we same page in SharePoint but depending upon the group to which a user belongs we can hide and show a promoted links.

First create some groups and assign user to a particular groups and than change the permission of promoted groups to show/hide that particular group.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using both of the solutions listed above on the same site to meet different needs.

I have one Promoted Links list that provides 'activity' links for a number of different user types. In order to keep the user experience simple for users I'm setting permissions on individual items in the Promoted Links list to hide specific tiles/links from groups that don't need to see them.

On the list, you need to break permissions with the site, then change the permissions on the specific tiles you're 'hiding'. 
I'm using SharePoint security groups to set permissions.

I'm using a second list to provide additional links on the page, but want to hide some of the links - sort of an active/inactive thing. Rather than adding a new field (which I haven't tested yet) I'm using the Order field as a filter. For example: If Order is less than 100, show them.

You can create the new view either in the browser (the 'Standard View' template will give you a tile view - surprisingly) or use the solution above for adding a view using SharePoint Designer. Either method will allow you to set a filter, sort, etc.

Alternatively, if you want to create another list type view, you can create a new view and use 'All Promoted Links' as a starting point.

Comment: part of your answer "(the 'Standard View' template will give you a tile view - surprisingly) " fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create different views for different users using SharePoint Designer.

Below are the step by step guides.

1. Click on any blank region of the Promoted Links. This will show the ribbon for that Promoted Link.
2. Click List tab on the ribbon.
3. Click Create View.
   [image]
4. Click Custom View in SharePoint Designer
   [image]
5. Allow it to open in SharePoint Designer.
6. Give a name for your view, e.g. **Test** and click OK. By default, SharePoint designer takes **Tiles** view. 
   [image]
7. Close SharePoint designer and go back to your Promoted Links in browser.
8. Click the **List** Tab on ribbon.
9. Select the view you just created from the dropdown menu.
   [image]
10. Click Modify View.
11. You can hide or display any link by giving a suitable condition for filter.